# How to convert two array into map in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays that look like this:

```
array1 = ["org1", "org2", "org3"];
array2 = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

Using JavaScript, I want to convert two arrays of same length into array of objects that would look like this:

```
orgMSPID = [{"org1": "a"},{"org2": "b"}, {"org3": "c"}]
```

Please anybody suggest me how to convert it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the `array1` and use `[]` for the dynamic key of the object.

```js
const array1 = ["org1", "org2", "org3"];
const array2 = ["a", "b", "c"];

const orgMPSID = array1.map((key, index) => ({ [key]: array2[index] }));

console.log(orgMPSID);
```

Comment: thanks for answer however if I want to access specific key value how can access it in this?

Comment: as i mentioned in the answer, use `[]` to specify dynamic key

Comment: could to please give example of that?

Comment: if no bracket like { key: "123"}, this will indicate the {key: "123"}, if you specify bracket like { [key]: "123" }, then key is the variable defined above (lets assume const key="abc"}, and the final result will be {abc: "123"}

Answer (score 1):

Zipping two (or more) arrays together is quite a common operation. If you use a library with helpers, chances are big that it includes a helper function for this (often named `zip`). If you aren't using a helper library consider adding a `zip` function yourself.

```
zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]) //=> [[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]]
```

Each entry within this result can then easily be transformed into an object using any of the lines below:

```
entries.map(entry => Object.fromEntries(Array.of(pair)));
entries.map(entry => Object.fromEntries([entry]));
entries.map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));
```

```js
const zip = (...args) => args[0].map((_, i) => args.map(arg => arg[i]));

const array1 = ["org1", "org2", "org3"];
const array2 = ["a", "b", "c"];

const result = zip(array1, array2).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Some libraries that provide a `zip` function also sometimes have `zipWith` which allows you to do the zipping and mapping as one call. [Using Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#zipWith), that's `_.zipWith(array1, array2, (key, value) => ({[key]: value}))` while [using Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith) the function is the first argument: `R.zipWith((key, value) => ({[key]: value}), array1, array2)`

Comment: @VLAZ you solve my lots of issue with comment as using Lodash its amazing library. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = ["org1", "org2", "org3"];
let array2 = ["a", "b", "c"];
let array3 = [];

for(let i=0; i< array1.length; i++){
 let item = {};
 item[array1[i]]=array2[i];
 array3.push(item)
}

console.log(array3);
```

Comment: thanks for answer however if I want to access specific key value how can access it in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

You iterate through `array1`, and use the current index to reference `array2` (or you could flip it the other way instead).

```js
const array1 = ["org1", "org2", "org3"];
const array2 = ["a", "b", "c"];
const orgMSPID = array1.reduce((c, e, i) => {
  c.push({ [e] : array2[i] });
  return c;
}, []);
console.log(orgMSPID);
```

Comment: thanks for answer however if I want to access specific key value how can access it in this?